# NSMutableArray is not instantiated as expected

Tags: objective-c

I am developing a class in Objective C which contains two arrays **audioFiles** and **files**. Files array contains all the names of the audio files and audioFiles is an array to hold AVAudioFile generated from the items in files array.

I want to instantiate both the array when I create a class instance.

> AudioPlayer *player = [[AudioPlayer alloc] init];

But I am unable to instantiate the audioFiles array as its showing nothing (nil). I put both the arrays in the implementation because I don't want to expose these two arrays outside of my class.

Could you please help me to fix the problem?

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "AudioPlayer.h"

@implementation AudioPlayer
{  
    NSMutableArray *audioFiles;    
    NSArray *files;    
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        files = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three",@"four", nil];

        [self createAudioFiles];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) createAudioFiles{
    for (int i = 0; i < [files count]; i++) {
        NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] files[i] ofType:@"wav"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
        AVAudioFile *file = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:url error:nil];
        [audioFiles addObject:file];
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing the `audioFiles` at all, you need to add:

```
audioFiles = [NSMutableArray array];
```

to your `init` or at the beginning of `createAudioFiles` method.

If you don't plan to add more objects after initialization, there is no need to keep the array mutable though, just declare it as `NSArray *audioFiles;` and change your method to:

```
-(void) createAudioFiles{
    NSMutableArray *buffer = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i < [files count]; i++) {
        NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] files[i] ofType:@"wav"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
        AVAudioFile *file = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:url error:nil];
        [buffer addObject:file];
    }

    audioFiles = [buffer copy]; // make it immutable
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am quite new in objective c world and I will make the array immutable as I don't need to add files later.